# Qual é o significado da expressão "dar á língua"?

Tags: significado, expressões, português-europeu, significado-em-contexto

Texto:

> Podemos descansar, **dar à língua** ou simplesemente não pensar em nada.

Há alguns sinônimos?

Comment: Acredito que seja um diminutivo de "dar com a língua nos dentes", que seria "tagarelar", "delatar", "trair um cúmplice", no sentido de estar revelando um segredo, por exemplo.

Comment: @Viana, em Portugal, *dar à língua*, significa simplesmente 'conversar descontraidamente'; creio que no Brasil poderiam dizer 'bater papo'. *Dar com a língua nos dentes* é que significa 'revelar segredos'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Portugal, ***dar à língua*** significa conversar descontraidamente, pelo prazer de conversar; pelo prazer de contar, saber e discutir as novidades, nomeadamente, mas não só, sobre a vida privada dos outros, escândalos do futebol, e outros assuntos igualmente “importantes”. É esse o significado de *dar à língua* no teu exemplo.

Um bom sinónimo é [*cavaquear* (Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cavaquear). [*Tagarelar* (Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/tagarelar) pode em contexto significar o mesmo, mas usa-se normalmente mais acerca de uma pessoa que fala de mais. Simplesmente [*conversar* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/conversar) não implica que a conversa seja descontraída e inconsequente, mas no contexto certo, como é o caso do teu exemplo, também serve. Já ***ficar/estar na conversa*** significa exatamente o mesmo que *ficar/estar a dar à língua*. O teu exemplo poderia ser reformulado como:

> Podemos descansar, ficar na conversa, ou simplesmente não pensar em nada.
>
> Podemos descansar, cavaquear/tagarelar/conversar, ou simplesmente não pensar em nada.

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) e o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/l%C3%ADngua) restringem este significado de *dar à língua* a Portugal, mas o [Aulete (língua)](http://www.aulete.com.br/l%C3%ADngua) não faz qualquer restrição. Eu encontro-o na literatura brasileira do século XIX; talvez tenha caído em desuso entretanto.

Vários dicionários, mas não o normalmente completíssimo [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/l%C3%ADngua), dizem que *dar à língua* pode também significar *dar com a língua nos dentes* (no Brasil, também *bater com a língua nos dentes*), que significa revelar segredos, fazer inconfidências, ser indiscreto. Não creio que alguma vez tenha ouvido *dar à língua* especificamente com este significado. É claro, que pode inferir-se esse significado se o contexto for apropriado; o mesmo se passa com *falar*, que também não significa especificamente ‘revelar segredos’:

> Pedimos-lhe que não contasse a ninguém, e ele foi logo falar/dar à língua.

Deixo aqui uns exemplos de uso de *dar à língua*. O primeiro é de um autor brasileiro, mas já é de 1882 (negrito meu em todos as citações):

> Vários sujeitos se ergueram logo, e lá se foram retirando vagarosamente; outros se deixaram ficar ainda a beber e a **dar à língua**.
>   [Aluísio Azevedo, *Girândola de Amores*, 1882.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=sX9cAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT52&dq=%22dar%20%C3%A0%20l%C3%ADngua%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi47Liq3sPbAhXky4MKHQ6JBf8Q6AEIuwIwJQ#v=onepage&q=%22dar%20%C3%A0%20l%C3%ADngua%22&f=false)
>
> Simpático no trato, [António Francisco Avillez] tem uma outra ocupação, que é a de conversar. Facilmente se fica horas a trovar ideias e a aprender com ele. Ao contrário de muitos dos que gostam de **dar à língua**, António Francisco Avillez sabe ouvir, podendo assim afirmar-se que é um bom conversador.
>   [João Barbosa, *Grande Reserva*, 2011.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=7L2qtJAUOf0C&pg=PT32&dq=%22dar%20%C3%A0%20l%C3%ADngua%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi47Liq3sPbAhXky4MKHQ6JBf8Q6AEIwgIwJg#v=onepage&q=%22dar%20%C3%A0%20l%C3%ADngua%22&f=false)
>
> Portanto, eles em casa devem falar mais com os azulejos da cozinha do que com a pessoa com que vivem, depois passam o dia todo no trabalho a **dar à língua**, e à noite, numa ocasião especial, vão estar calados para um restaurante.
>   [Bruno Nogueira e João Quadros, *Tubo de Ensaio*, 2011.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=3lek4tZBz2cC&pg=PT137&lpg=PT137&dq=%22a%20dar%20%C3%A0%20l%C3%ADngua%22&source=bl&ots=fYuOCBOtuG&sig=bYuJmbO3ExaMjor5nz1iabGWgg4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHh5eE6MPbAhWi3YMKHY6rCnIQ6AEIfTAR#v=onepage&q=%22a%20dar%20%C3%A0%20l%C3%ADngua%22&f=false)